# PostgreSQL data migration from one database to other database in AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dump, data-migration, dblink

I have my Old postgres database which is not a cloud based. And I want to migrate the data from the old database to new database which is in aws.

So can this be done via dblink or what is the other best practises to do this.

Comment: I think you want pg_dump and pg_restore as the names say to dump and restore a database

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate DBs to AWS via AWS Database Migration Service. It's fully managed tool to help you move your data from on premises to AWS. You can read more about it here: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/?nc=sn&loc=1.